# Flurry Analytics and Angularjs not show changes in Dashboard

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, analytics, flurry

I added Flurry to my Angularjs project following this [link](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-flurry) and I added a couple of events.

In the View:

```
<div class="row button no-gutters">
    <button analytics-on="click" analytics-event="Button search action" analytics-category="Commands" class="buttonSubmit" ng-click="searchAction()"</button>
</div>
```

In the Controller:

```
$analytics.eventTrack('in home');
```

Automatically this two events appears in my Flurry Dashboard and are showed in the Event Logs:

[image]

But in "Event Summary" of my Flurry Dashboard all values is always 0 and don't change. I don't have any errors in the web browser console.

[image]

This values should be change, right? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Flurry needs 24h for update all statistics.

I don't delete this question because it's a bit confusing that Flurry doesn't update all statistics (event logs appears before all statistics) in real time the first time.